# dispose() is not the same as setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, windowlistener

I noticed that if `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` is set, closing the frame will end its Process in Task Manager, but if i implement WindowListener and manually dispose() the frame, Process will remain... probably because in 
new Runnable() i have something like this:

```
new Runnable() {
    void run() {
    Jsch tunnel=new Jsch();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() { frame.dispose(); } ); // imagine that this is legal 
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Anyone can tell me, how to manually end process created by some application?

Comment: `probably because in new Runnable() i have something like this:` - correct. dispose() will end the process if you are disposing the last window created by the application. But since you are closing one frame and opening another the Java task is still running. `how to manually end process created by some application?` - Not sure what you expect to happen because the process is still running because of the new frame. Maybe you could use the `ProcessBuilder` class to start a new process so the old process can end. However the new process would still show up in the Task Manager I would guess.

Comment: A moment, do you treat Jsch as frame... because i don't understand for which "new frame" you are talking in last answer...

Comment: Depends on process itself. For example, if you have something like swing timer, best way to stop it is by using `WindowListener` (by calling `stop` method in overriden `windowClosed method`). Btw, personally, I always use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE as a default close operation. Just to make things safe.

Comment: @JovanMeshkov, I misread the question. But yes, I'm guessing that a Jsch class is some kind of Window, therefore the process will NOT close automactially when you use dispose(). You can still force the application to close by using System.exit() from within your WindowListener.

Comment: @camickr Yeah, as tackline said. I could accept your answer if you answered, how ever, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).

> - EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.

So to force an exit call `System.exit(0);`.

When all top level windows are disposed, the AWT Event Dispatch Thread can be shut down (a new one can be create if needed). When there are no non-daemon threads left in the process, it will exit.