# dispose() vs setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Tags: java, swing

I have been searching around quite a bit about this topic but never got any satisfaction about any answers so ended up asking a question here :). Anyways, 
from this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266202/dispose-is-not-the-same-as-setdefaultcloseoperationjframe-exit-on-close) it was clear that `dispose()` does not terminate all the processes and still has remains in the `task manager`(the AWT process is not terminated completely) even after the `JFrame` is closed.

**So, my question is :-**

1. does **`this.dispose()`** cleans off every child process after disposing the JFrame? or  **`setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`** does this job instead.
2. Which one will be *good to go with* performance-wise, if I am developing applications for low spec PCs

Thanks, any suggestion on this is appreciated.

Comment: I recommend `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` over `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the performance implications, after all, how many times do you expect users to exit your application per second? :)

Comment: That is true indeed. @biziclop. But still wanted to know the specifications of both the components. Thanks though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer 1.

`dispose()` on a `JFrame` will destroy the window and have the operating system clean up after it, if its the only `JFrame` left, the Java VM might terminate. So, in summary, it will close the window, and if the JFrame is the last remaining window of your application, it might (or might not) terminate your VM.

`setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` however, will call `System.exit()` when the `JFrame` is closed, terminating the VM regardless of there being any other active `JFrames` in your app.

So, they are two different things :-)

To answer your second question, you could test it. But honestly, I wouldn't be to worried about this.

Comment: that won't be a matter of concern though as you and @biziclop are saying, but does it also close the connections to DB and other resources?

Comment: @mustangDC No, it won't. `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` only disposes of the window and the native resources required to display it. (Which often is good, imagine the scenario where you want the program to run in the background with a small icon in the task tray.)

Comment: Thats a good idea @biziclop for an application of such a need. Cheers